# re split special case to split comma-separated strings

Tags: python, regex

I want to use python re.split() to split a sentence into multiple strings by commas, but I don't want apply on single words separated by commas such as:

Example

```
s = "Yes, alcohol can have a place in a healthy diet."
desired result = ["Yes, alcohol can have a place in a healthy diet."]
```

another example:

```
s = "But, of course, excess alcohol is terribly harmful to health in a variety of ways, and even moderatealcohol intake is associated with an increase in the number two cause of premature death: cancer."
desired output = ["But, of course" , "excess alcohol is terribly harmful to health in a variety of ways" , "and even moderatealcohol intake is associated with an increase in the number two cause of premature death: cancer."]
```

Any pointers? please.

Comment: Perhaps you should split on commas and then recombine the single words with the next phrase.  Also, what if there are multiple such words "Hey, hey, hey, yes, of course, . . ."?

Comment: @depperm, I tried like sep = re.split('(?<!\d)[,](?!\d)', string) and others no one seems to be bullet-proof

Comment: @GordonLinoff, for multiple words, I have no such requirement that they need to be split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python doesn't support variable-length [lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in regex, I'd use `re.findall()` instead:

```
In [3]: re.findall(r"\s*((?:\w+,)?[^,]+)",s)
Out[3]:
['But, of course',
 'excess alcohol is terribly harmful to health in a variety of ways',
 'and even moderatealcohol intake is associated with an increase in the number two cause of premature death: cancer.']
```

**Explanation:**

```
\s*        # Match optional leading whitespace, don't capture that
(          # Capture in group 1:
 (?:\w+,)? #  optionally: A single "word", followed by a comma 
 [^,]+     #  and/or one or more characters except commas
)          # End of group 1
```

Comment: an extra request, can we modify the regex to meet the following the requirement. ["Cancers of the head and neck, esophagus, liver, colon, and rectum and breast are associated with drinking alcohol."]

Comment: Difficult. Will your input only contain a single sentence, or could there be more than one? If the latter, you should first use NLP tools to split the input into individual sentences. Then I think it could be done.

Comment: Yes, my input contains a single sentence because I'm already using NLP to split a large string into individual sentences. :)